# Where to use a javascript function called "freeze"

Tags: javascript, function

What scene does this code useful?

```
freeze = function(o) { return o; };
```

I read someone's code like this.

```
var obj = freeze({name: "Samuel-ZSJ", getName:function(){ return this.name; }});
```

Comment: That function is pointless. Where did you see it?

Comment: It's the identity function. If you are really doing FP it's quite handy. Only the `freeze` for it is kind of... odd.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

About javascript function freeze. See in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff806186%28v=vs.94%29.aspx

Comment: But your link is about `Object.freeze()`, and the question is about a user-defined `freeze()`.

Comment: thanks to [swenon](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1298089/swemon) and [nnnnnn](http://stackoverflow.com/users/615754/nnnnnn), finally I got the message.

Answer (score 6):

It is:

1. A joke
2. A stub function to implement it later
3. A developer didn't know what they are doing

Pick any you like more.

So, personally I cannot think of how this function could be useful.

Comment: 1. so it's in the refrigerator web UI where it's probably used.